# Zend keep front controller from blocking image requests

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller, zend-config

Anytime I use an `<img>` tag in my Zend Framework application, no image is displayed.  When I type the absolute path into the address bar, the front controller attempts to find an "images" controller.

There HAS to be a way I can use `<img src="/public/images/logo.png">` in Zend Framework right?

I've tried it from within views, layouts, and helpers, and no luck. I've also used the `$this->baseURL()` technique, and the `serverURL()` technique by getting the info from the Front Controller, but it still won't show the image... anywhere on the site.  (I have the same problem with including css files unless I do an `@import('/css/main.css')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an problem with your .htaccess file
you have to exclude this files from the reWrite rule, otherwise those requests are routed to index.php.

**/public/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the answer.  Your web server (and not ZF) should be configured to serve static files instead of rewriting the URLs to index.php.

Comment: so I guess that Rewrite Rule mean's DON'T route requests with an extension (of those types) to index.php?  I did see that in the documentation, but I thought it meant route any request of type (etc...) to index.php

Comment: Also, according to Zend's documentation, it shouldn't route anything under the document_root (anything in the /public folder) to the Rewrite Anyways?  I plugged the above line into the .htaccess file, not getting results. Here's my file now: `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`